# How to do a query only on a specific admin page?

Tags: wp-query, wp-admin

I'm making a page for settings API using Codestar Framework, and loading fields using their [filterable configure](http://codestarframework.com/documentation/#configuration) - **question is not related to Codestar**. In one of such dropdown field, I need to load all the posts from a custom post type that are added within 30 days. To make the things nice and clean I made a custom function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get posts of last 30 days only.
 * 
 * @return array Array of posts.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function pre_get_active_posts_of_30_days() {

    //admin-only function
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    global $project_prefix; //set a project prefix (i.e. pre_)
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query(
                            array(
                                'post_type'         => 'cpt',
                                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                                'date_query'        => array(
                                                        array(
                                                            'after'     => '30 days ago',
                                                            'inclusive' => true,
                                                        ),
                                                    )
                            )
                        );

    $posts_this_month = array();

    if( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) : $latest_posts->the_post();

        $validity_type  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "{$project_prefix}validity_type", true );
        if( $validity_type && 'validity date' === $validity_type ) {
            $validity   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "{$project_prefix}validity", true );
            $tag        = days_until( $validity ) .' days left'; //custom function
        } else if( $validity_type && 'validity stock' === $validity_type ) {
            $tag        = 'Stock';
        } else {
            $tag        = '...';
        }

        $posts_this_month[get_the_ID()] = get_the_title() .' ['. $tag .']';

    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();

    return $posts_this_month;
}
```

Question is not even with the function.

I want to do the query **only on that particular top_level_custom-settings-api page**. The function is loading on every page load of admin. I tried using `get_current_screen()` but this function's giving me not found fatal error.

#### Edit

No @bonger, I remembered that. I tried your code in this way:

```
add_action('current_screen', 'current_screen_callback');
function current_screen_callback($screen) {
    if( is_object($screen) && $screen->id == 'top_level_custom-settings-api' ) {
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'pre_get_active_posts_of_30_days' );
    }
}
```

The code does work well, but it doesn't control my function loading only on that particular page. I checked the query on other pages, the query is there too. And I tried changing the conditional to something wrong, like `$screen->id == 'top_level_-api'`, it still works that way. :(

I'm afraid, I know I have a serious lack in behind-the-scene action and filter things. Would love to have a good read for that too.

Comment: You've forgotten this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/174586/57034 ?!

Comment: no @bonger I remembered that. Updated my query.

Comment: This is probably a dumb comment but what happens if you do `1 == 2` - in theory that should stop it from loading on all the pages but is that what happens? Just to verify that it's the conditional that needs refining and not the hook.

Comment: That's actually @cybmeta 's code, but isn't it the `cs_framework_options` filter or whatever (haven't used Codestar Framework) that should be conditionally added, not `admin_init`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'm afraid, I can't get your point, cz I'm numb at it. Could you please provide me an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's worthwhile pointing out that using `admin_init` within the `current_screen` filter is too late because `admin_init` has already fired.

Instead do:

```
add_action('current_screen', 'current_screen_callback');

function current_screen_callback($screen) {
    if( is_object($screen) && $screen->id === 'top_level_custom-settings-api' ) {
        add_filter('top_level_screen', '__return_true');
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in your `top_level_page_callback` callback responsible for executing the query:

```
function top_level_page_callback() {

    $active_posts = null;

    if ( ($is_top_level = apply_filters('top_level_screen', false)) ) {

        $active_posts = pre_get_active_posts_of_30_days();

    }

    //etc...

}
```

That's one way to do it...

Or you could use, `add_action('load-top_level_custom-settings-api', 'callback');`

Other than the `current_screen` hook, where else were you trying to call `pre_get_active_posts_of_30_days()` from? Because you had to have been calling it in a global scope of some sort for it to be running on all pages and not just the target page.

Answer (score 1):

Just do that

```
/**
 * Make sure to do WP_Query (or whatever) only on specific admin page.
 */

// save current page slug
$current_page_slug = '';

// get current page slug
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $current_page_slug = $_GET['page'];
}

// we are not inside our 'specific_page_slug' page? go back
if ($current_page_slug !== 'specific_page_slug') {
    return; // or do whatever
}

// here we are inside our 'specific_page_slug' page
// so now you can do wp_query or whatever
```